# How to do I make variables in filemaker using strings in feild

Tags: filemaker

I have a field where the user can input text and I want them to be able to insert tags like

```
 <impact>
```

or

```
 <signature>
```

as representation of where I would like to insert an html img. . So if I can somehow extract that tag from the text field into a variable that I can use for the substitution. If I were to write out the processes it would be like this.

get a list of every tag in the specified field
loop through the list keeping track of where it is in the text
set the tag to a var $tag = tagfound 
substitute the tag

```
  Substitute (  texfield;  "<$tag>"; '<img src=\"cid:$tag\'>" ;
```

and at this point I would also do other things with the $tag before i went on to the next itteration

anyone know if this is possible /how to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take 2 (thanks for the clarification):

Since you need to loop, you need either a script or a custom function. I'll show you with a script since everyone has scriptmaker (whereas you need FMPA to get access to custom functions).

The result will be in a variable called $tag_list which you can do what you want with afterwards.

[image: FileMaker script screen shot]

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with this but it is certainly is the right direction thank you !

Comment: It's starting in the right place but not ending in the correct place

Comment: Added a screen shot of tested, functional script.

Answer (score 1):

You use the let function to assign variables in a FileMaker calculation:

```
Let (
[
$impact = '<impact>';
$signature = '<signature>' // Notice that the semi-colon is on the next line and not this one.
];

Substitute ( textfield; $impact; 'replacement text')

) // End Let function.
```

You can also use let as sort of like a script to make multiple changes like so:

```
Let (
[
$impact = '<impact>';
$signature = '<signature>';

$impact_replaced = Substitute ( textfield; $impact; 'replacement text');
$signature_replaced = Substitute ( $impact_replaced; $signature; 'replacement text')
];

$signature_replaced // This is the return value from the calculation.

)
```

Comment: that's all well and good but I don't want to write code for every possible tag. I need to find all the tags in the textfield somehow then loop through them

Comment: I am not sure I understand what it is you are trying to do. What do you mean by find all the tags?

Comment: Is your goal to find anything wrapped in '<' '>'?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "use the tags as variables", if the tags are known in advance just do a Substitute like:

Substitute ( text ; "<tag>" ; "newvalue" )

You can also nest multiple substitutes, check the docs for details.

Comment: eyah I know I can just do that but the list can change at any time and I can't spend the time moding the substitute every time and I need to use the tag for something else besides the substitute I'll modify my post with more detail

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this custom function](http://edoshin.typepad.com/bits_and_pieces/2005/11/merge_expressio.html) may help.